# Loop through same set of .ts files to imitate a live stream?

Tags: http-live-streaming, live-streaming, hlsl

We have a video stream coming to a CDN from an origin which is a TV stream. We need to switch the origin from CDN to a pre-rendered set of static video m3u8 package. The CDN supports switching origin. How do I sync my static hls package with video stream, like media stream sequence number? How to seamlessly make this switch possible?

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to loop a VOD as a livestream. EXT-X-START updates the position of the stream. Works fine in safari but not in safari and chrome browser. my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146108/create-fake-hls-live-stream-from-single-video-and-loop