# Create fake hls live stream from single video and loop

Tags: node.js, encoding, http-live-streaming, video.js, m3u8

I am trying to simulate a live stream from a single video encoded as .ts files. The playlist files looks like, example:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-START:TIME-OFFSET=9.56,PRECISE=YES
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:30.6250,
https://example.com/720p0.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:29.5000,
https://example.com/720p1.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:32.8750,
https://example.com/720p2.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:30.8750,
https://example.com/720p3.ts
```

The #EXT-X-START:TIME-OFFSET=,PRECISE=YES
 indicates where the video should be played from which gets updated whenever a new rendition is requested. In safari the stream loops when the #EXT-X-START:TIME-OFFSET value is updated to 0 and so on, but in chrome and firefox, the stream goes into a endless buffering. I am using videojs for my player.

Is there any solution to have the m3u8 manifest loop in firefox and chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The hls spec is confusing at best, it can be pain.

try [X9K3](https://github.com/futzu/x9k3)

I just added fake live streaming to x9k3 a few weeks ago.
x9k3 segments mpegts to hls.

To simulate live playback, x9k3 throttles itself.
*If a segment is two seconds in duration,
x9k3 takes two seconds to create the segment and update the m3u8.*

It does not loop a file, however, that would be trivial to add.

https://github.com/futzu/x9k3#stream-diff

Comment: Thanks but i am looking for a nodejs implementation where I can easily manipulate the playlist and easily add ads ets..

Comment: Ad wise, X9K3 has full SCTE-35 support, I couldn't find any other parser with SCTE35 or the fake live thing.

Comment: I did want to ask, if you don't mind the question, if you aren't using SCTE35, what do you you use for ads? I'm trying to make x9k3 as complete as possible.